# Iphone - Update the View Controller with the chosen application settings after pressing back

Tags: iphone, button, settings, back

I'm defining 2 fields in my settings' application.
When the user opens the application, the 2 fields defined in the settings are shown correctly. If the user changes the settings and then open my application again, the 2 fields aren't updated. They are only correctly updated when I restart the debugger. I added the refreshFields method to the **viewWillAppear**.

However, **viewWillAppear** isn't caught when I click on the back button on the phone and then open the application again.
If instead of clicking the back button on the phone, I click on a back button created in my application, then everything works fine.

In conclusion, where should I call the refreshFields method, so that they are caught when my application is opened for the 2nd time after clicking the back button on the phone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution is adding the following in the viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshFields) name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

However, the screen appears for a few milliseconds with the old values, since the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is caught after the screen appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at UIApplicationDelegate:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

> You should use this method to restart
>   any tasks that were paused (or not yet
>   started) while the application was
>   inactive. For example, you could use
>   it to restart timers or throttle up
>   OpenGL ES frame rates. If your
>   application was previously in the
>   background, you could also use it to
>   refresh your application’s user
>   interface.

Comment: This method is caught after the screen is loaded. So the screen appears with the old values for some milliseconds and then the new values are replaced. I tried to find a method in the UIApplicationDelegate that would be caught immediately before the screen becomes active, but I didn't have any luck. Any ideas?